# Auto complete can't sort the json data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="searchbox">
```

**JS**

I was getting entire json data in auto complete but it didn't sorted according to search value.

```
$( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
  source: function selectVal(request, response) {
    var value = $("#dropdown_btn").val();
    $.ajax({
      url:"search.php",
      type:"post",
      dataType:"json",
      data:{value:value},
      success:function(data) {
        response(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: "didn't sorted according to search value" do you mean to say sorted data should show in dropdown?

Comment: try data.sort()

Comment: Where do you expect the sorting to take place? You haven't shown us any code that's trying to sort anything? `autocomplete` simply shows what it gets. It doesn't know what order you want to show the results in.

Comment: I added HTML search box.please check @Magnus Eriksson

Comment: @BhaskararaoGummidi:  what is your json format because if it's  an array then data.sort will apply easily.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. If you want the results to be sorted, _you_ need to do it somewhere. Either you sort it in your back end (search.php) or sort the results in the ajax callback.

Comment: I used Jquery ui plugin. It's calling a function when i try to console.log @Dipak chavda

Comment: Please suggest me any other jquery plug in to auto complete

Comment: @BhaskararaoGummidi: can you do one thing just sort response data before send to client. it may easy to you.

Comment: I required search.php response format

Comment: @BhaskararaoGummidi: do you try sorting from server side?

Comment: sorting or any manipulation of data should be done on the server side, your code dosent shows it. autocomplete only shows fetched data sorted or unsorted

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var value = $("#dropdown_btn").val();
$( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: function( request, response ) {
      $.ajax({
        url:"search.php",
        type:"post",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data:{value:value},
        success: function( data ) {
          response( data );
        }
    });
  }
});
```